# User profile sort by questions answered state

Tags: feature-request

In order to not cluttering Stack Overflow with unanswered questions I'm trying to edit/update my own questions foremost. So it more likely will be eventually answered.

The problem is that there is no simple sort by answered/unanswered questions in user profile - only by votes/activity/newest/views. And it was simple to maintain unanswered questions when its number was less than 20 so fits in single page. But its number grows and maintaining becomes more difficult.

---

Why such sorting is not implemented? Is it in fact useless or what? I understand that one may use filtering in search engine but for own questions its an overkill I suppose.

**EDIT:**

Partially related [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387421/favorites-organizing) proposing too much overhead (adding grouping/filtering to questions/answer) for user profile seems like has negative answer. But here I think it is a someway different situation - proposed sorting `overhead` seems like being not so difficult to implement because of existence of same functionality (sorting) already. And its functionality still needed as I tried to explaine earlier.

Comment: Reasoning same way there is no need in user profile at all. The badge with reputation is enough. All ones questions/answers may be simply find in single search form. Without any _overkill_.

Comment: `user:10711194 answers:0` do this and you will get your unanswered ones. Why is there a need for separate sorting? If you want more per page, then at the bottom, there is an option to increase results per page