# Favorites organizing

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

There is no simple way to organize favorites in one's user profile (only sorting). But one may definitely wants to for example grouping/filtering favorites in order to quickly find saved answer. Same in less extent but also refers to ones questions/answers.

---

Will such grouping/filtering feature be useful or there is already same functionality somewhere?

**EDIT:**

There is an option to use Stack Overflow search engine for these purposes. But I think for *user* it is not close enough to the desired functionality. That is why:

- All filters (tags/language/date...) here must be done only by writing corresponding one in search form. Compare it with mouse switching between questions/answers/badges/.. in user profile which is much more user-friendly.
- There is no ability to add/edit custom "tag" in order to organize Q/A for further fast searching (i.e not possibility for grouping - referred "tag" would be group name for example).
- While typing there is a quite big possibility to make a typo especially when your filtering contains more than 2 filters. But if it would be organized in profile - user will hardly miss-click desired "tag" (well it might happen as well of course but the chance of it is much lesser than typing 20-40 symbols with mistakes). Again we would get a speedup here as well.

Comment: [Close enough](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A1&mixed=1)?

Comment: Your browser can store bookmarks, so you only have to type it once. Alternatively  use SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=favorite+tag

Comment: @rene is composing queries in SEDE more user-friendly than queries in search form?

Comment: @rene also bookmarks functionality at first sight should work. Is it an answer - "use" outside apps not SO itself?

Comment: I have no problem with it. I'm 100% sure the developer time is better spend on more pressing features then offering an search / sort on users favorites, specially when other options are available that are also more flexible.

Comment: I may build such a service. Are you interested?

Comment: @PeterMortensen to the degree to ask it in the meta. Actually I'm new here so have no much favorites by the time - so for me it's not big deal. Just question arisen - question asked (I believe this site is exactly for that).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer here is that such a feature would be too much overhead to implement in users' profiles. And at the same time, some alternatives exist:

1. "CLI" for such functionality. I'm talking about a search engine. It is not intended to be user-friendly as well as it doesn't provide the full desired features, but it may serve to a degree.
2. More user-friendly option is to use browser bookmarks or any other "external" for Stack Overflow service like [pocket](https://app.getpocket.com/) for example. Here seems like no drawbacks except following minors:

   - it's an "external" solution which means it decreases user reliability on site services (because one need to go somewhere in order to go to Stack Overflow).
   - some users use favorites only as bookmarks and if they actually need to bookmark/organize it somewhere instead - it will again decrease using embedded in Stack Overflow functions for that. Up to not using such functionality here at all.

So even if for *user* experience it might be better to embed organize tools into one's profile it is not so desired for *Stack Overflow user*. And that is why the answer is this functionality is not so needed at the moment.